# stdout/stderr - ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script that was working fine in python 2.7 but now in 3.6 it's failing.  Particularly I am having issues at this point

The function below is being called by the following line of code:

```
exec_command(ssh, 'systemctl status myservice', timeout=60)
```

Which then executes the function.  ssh in this case is an ssh connection using paramiko.

```
def exec_command(ssh, cmd, timeout, want_exitcode=False):
    # one channel per command
    stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
    # get the shared channel for stdout/stderr
    channel = stdout.channel

    # indicate that we're not going to write to that channel anymore
    channel.shutdown_write()

    # read stdout/stderr in order to prevent read block hangs
    stdout_chunks = []
    stdout_chunks.append(stdout.channel.recv(len(stdout.channel.in_buffer)))
```

When running I get the following error:

File "path\myscript.py", line 54, in exec_command
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
[13340] Failed to execute script myscript

Line 54 is `stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)`

Comment: You should do `print(ssh.exec_command(cmd))` to find out how many values are being returned. Then figure out which ones are of your interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never said what `ssh.exec_command` is, but I assume you're using paramiko to access some ssh server.

As you can see in the documentation here http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command this function returns 3 values, not 2... So you should change the line to:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
```

Now I'm not sure why it was working before. Maybe paramiko api changed?